# Is it possible to use EJB with a class that has generics type bound?

Tags: java, ejb

When using EJB with a class like below with generics, are multiple EJB's created for each generic type?  If not, how does it actually work, if at all?

Thanks in advance.

```
@Stateless(mappedName="blah")
public class Blah<T>  {
    public void doSomething(T obj) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        list.add(obj);
        return list;
    }
}

public class BlahUser1 {
    @EJB
    private Blah<Integer> blah;
}

public class BlahUser2 {
    @EJB
    private Blah<String> blah;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sorry.

And the issue isn't even Java's [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), but EJBs.

The `@Stateless` annotation generally creates a pool of instances (depends on the application server, technically) and saves them for future usage for performance reasons.  The application server is going to use `new` to create a few instances of `Blah` and do the necessary injection.

But it can't do that in your case, because `Blah<T>` is not completely specified.

However, you can use [CDI](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_obtaining_a_contextual_instance_by_programmatic_lookup) to achieve something similar to this.  Are you sure you need EJBs?  (Answer could be yes, so don't refactor everything to use CDI!)